# Inkscape free shape from square

Tags: inkscape

I have a square. I know I can scale, rotate and skew. But can I move each corner without moving the others? I tried Path > Convert to Path, but it does not work. Any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving one corner without moving the others will convert the square into a four-sided polygon with four angles which is called a quadrilateral.

1. Click the second button from the top on the vertical toolbar on the left side to *Edit paths by nodes*. This button is marked by a black arrow in the screenshot.
2. Click the button marked by the mouse cursor in the screenshot to *Convert selected object's stroke to paths*.
3. Select any one of the square's four nodes and drag the node in the direction of inside the square to create a quadrilateral of the required shape. The selected node can be dragged either inside or outside of the boundary of the original square.

[image]